# The gradient cannot be calculated automatically

Tags: pytorch

I am a beginner of Deep Learning and trying to making discriminator that judge cats/non-cats.

But When I run the code following, runtime error occured.

I know that "requires_grad" must be set to True in order to calculate the gradient automatically, 
but since X_train and Y_train are variables for reading, they are set to False.

I would be grateful if you could modify this code.

```
X_train = torch.tensor(train_set_x, dtype=dtype,requires_grad=False)
Y_train = torch.tensor(train_set_y, dtype=dtype,requires_grad=False) 


def train_model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, n_h, num_iterations=10000,learning_rate=0.5, print_cost=False):
    """
    Arguments:
    X_train -- training set represented by a numpy array of shape (num_px * num_px * 3, m_train)
    Y_train -- training labels represented by a numpy array (vector) of shape (1, m_train)
    X_test -- test set represented by a numpy array of shape (num_px * num_px * 3, m_test)
    Y_test -- test labels represented by a numpy array (vector) of shape (1, m_test)
    n_h -- size of the hidden layer
    num_iterations -- number of iterations in gradient descent loop
    learning_rate -- hyperparameter representing the learning rate used in the update rule of optimize()
    print_cost -- if True, print the cost every 200 iterations

    Returns:
    d -- dictionary containing information about the model.
    """
    n_x = X.size(1)
    n_y = Y.size(1)

    # Create model
    model = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(n_x,n_h),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Linear(n_h,n_y),
          nn.ReLU()
        )

    # Initialize parameters
    for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        if name.find('weight') != -1:
            torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(param)
        elif name.find('bias') != -1:
            torch.nn.init.constant_(param, 0)

    # Cost function
    cost_fn = nn.BCELoss()

    # Loop (gradient descent)
    for i in range(0, num_iterations):

        # Forward propagation: compute predicted labels by passing input data to the model.
        Y_predicted = model(X_train)
        A2 = (Y_predicted > 0.5).float()

        # Cost function. Inputs: predicted and true values. Outputs: "cost".
        cost = cost_fn(A2, Y_train)

        # Print the cost every 100 iterations
        if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
            print("Cost after iteration %i: %f" % (i, cost.item()))

        # Zero the gradients before running the backward pass. See hint in problem description
        model.zero_grad()

        # Backpropagation. Compute gradient of the cost function with respect to all the 
        # learnable parameters of the model. Use autograd to compute the backward pass.
        cost.backward()

        # Gradient descent parameter update.
        with torch.no_grad():
            for param in model.parameters():
                # Your code here !!
                param -= learning_rate * param.grad

    d = {"model": model,
         "learning_rate": learning_rate,
         "num_iterations": num_iterations}

    return d
```

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are mixing numpy arrays and torch tensors. Pytorch tensors are a bit like numpy arrays, but they also kept in a computational graph that is responsible for the backward pass.

The description of your received variables `X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test` says they are numpy arrays. You should convert them all to torch tensors:

```
x = torch.tensor(x)
```

I also noticed that you are manually performing gradient updates. Unless that was your intention, I would recomend you using one of pytorch's optimizers.

```
from torch.optim import SGD

model = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(n_x,n_h),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Linear(n_h,n_y),
          nn.Sigmoid() # You are using BCELoss, you should give it an input from 0 to 1 
        )

optimizer = SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
cost_fn = nn.BCELoss() 

optimizer.zero_grad()
y = model(x)
cost = cost_fn(y, target)

cost.backward()
optimizer.step()  # << updated the gradients of your model
```

Notice that it is recomended to use `torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` instead of `BCELoss`. The first implements sigmoid and the binary cross entropy together with some math tricks to make it more numerically stable. Your model should look something like:

```
model = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(n_x,n_h),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Linear(n_h,n_y)
        )
```